# BIND9 - Noob issue on how to connect to the main domain

Tags: bind, debian-lenny

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid, but let's ask anyway.

I'm trying to create "hostnames" on my LAN machines (eg. when you ping "chris", Chris' machine - IP 12.34.56.78 - respond to that).
I'm doing this through a Debian (lenny) server with bind9, and using this server as the LAN's primary DNS server.

Problem: I **can** ping `whatever.chris` from other machines, but **not** `chris`. What am I doing wrong?

I followed these instructions to setup bind9: http://www.cahilig.net/2008/07/05/how-setup-lan-dns-server-using-bind9-under-debian-etch-and-ubuntu-804

**Files:**

*/etc/hostname*

```
chris
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.3 chris.chris chris

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
Didn't touch this one, as resolvconf overwrites it
```

*/etc/bind/name.conf.local*

```
zone "chris" {
        type master;
        file "db.chris";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "db.192.168.1";
};
```

*/var/cache/bind/db.chris*

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA main.chris. admin.chris. (
                2012051610      ;serial
                04800           ;refresh
                86400           ;retry
                60              ;expire
                604800          ;negative cache TTL
                )
@      IN      NS       main.chris.
@      IN      A        192.168.1.3
www    IN      A        192.168.1.3
main   IN      A        192.168.1.3
```

*/var/cache/bind/db.192.168.1*

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA main.chris. admin.chris. (
                2012051606      ;serial
                604800          ;refresh
                86400           ;retry
                60              ;expire
                604800          ;negative cache TTL
                )
@       IN      NS      main.chris.
1       IN      PTR     chris.
```

*/etc/bind/named.conf.options*

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        forwarders {
                192.168.1.1;
        };

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you put all these in one zone, lets call it "local", then add hosts to local like chris.local, john.local.  Then you want each of these machines to end up with `search local` in their `/etc/resolv.conf`,  This will make it so that when they `ping chris` it automatically will try to find an ip address for `chris.local` if `chris` isn't found.

Typically you would have your dhcp server send them this `search` directive, but it can also be configured using `resolvconf`

Comment: I changed that on _/etc/network/interfaces_, adding *dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3* and *dns-search chris* to it and restarting */etc/init.d/networking*, but it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the permissions on your zone file is correct. I believe it needs to be chmod 644, or was it 744. Once you have made the changes did you do: "/etc/init.d/named restart"  Also, for any hints on additional issues check your /var/log/messages for any pointers.

Your zone file should look like this.

http://pastebin.com/cB9SCJH0

Comment: I tried that but no luck. I'm still able to ping 'whatever.chris', but not 'chris' itself. 
Also, the log didn't give me anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do dns lookups by shortname (i.e. not just by fully-qualified domain names), then you are in the realm of /etc/resolv.conf and the 'search' parameter.

> search chris

man 5 resolv.conf for details